# Unable to spread an array inside a template literal

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component where I am trying to pass in values

meant to be used for linear gradient values in my styling.

colors is an array thus expecting it to be spreadable as follows.

```
...gradientProps.colors
```

But this doesn't work with following error:

> TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'Element' has no call
> signatures.

New to typescript and googling around shows spread operator works over an array.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
interface GradientProps {
    angle?: string;
    colors?: string[];
}

interface Props {
    // 10 other props
    gradientProps?: GradientProps;
}

const MyComponent = ({
  // 10 other props
  gradientProps,
}: Props): React.ReactElement => {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                // Error is with ${...gradientProps.colors}
                backgroundImage: `url('www.aaa.com/some.png') linear-gradient(${gradientProps.angle}, ${...gradientProps.colors})`,
            }}
        >
            {(<div>{''}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
};
```

With the props filled up after spreading, expecting the backgroundImage's value to look as follows:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, blue);
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of the spread to be?

Comment: @HereticMonkey comma separated values as follows. background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, blue); Also updated question with same.

Comment: When I do the following in a console: `var a = [1,2,3]; console.log(...a);` I get `1 2 3`, because it's the same as calling `console.log(1,2,3)`. You can't have `...a.toString()`; that's a syntax error. You could do `${gradientProps.colors.join()}` and it would get you what you want.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Appreciate it, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spread syntax is not a standalone construct. It can only be used in certain places. I'm rather partial to [MDN's documentation on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> **Spread syntax** (`...`) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

For this case, getting a comma-delimited list out of an array, is taken care of by good old [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), which by default, uses comma as a delimiter.

```
backgroundImage: `url('www.aaa.com/some.png') linear-gradient(${gradientProps.angle}, ${gradientProps.colors.join()})`,
```